# Client Feedback when SQL Server Offline

Tags: .net, sql-server, sqlclient

We have a very data centric application, which is often run across networks with questionable connectivity.

We want to feedback to clients when the database is offline, and display some kind of warning screen - with error information - until the network comes back and the database is available again. I'd like to display the same screen whenever the database is unavailable for any reason - ie: service stopped, paused, login failure, network off, etc.

I have a routine handling SQLClient.SQLException, which I then parse for SQLErrors and check the numbers, problem is there are loads of different error numbers for failures and I keep missing some.

Is there some simple, consistent way i can check if the database server is offline or unavailable? How do others handle this without letting some unhandled exception slip through?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can easily catch only sql exceptions like this:

```
try
{
... your code
{
catch(SqlException sqlEx)
{
... display your error page
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
... general error handling
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. This will catch ALL SQLExceptions and will give my users the database offline error even if there is a key violation or just a query  with bad syntax. I'd like to blame all my code fails on the database being offline, but I think I'd get caught out soon enough.. :) I want to be able to split the "unable to connect to database for some reason" errors from all the other SQLException errors. Thanks for taking the time to answer.

Comment: there's no nice way of doing what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try to create `SqlConnection` object with connection string for server I need to check connectivity to, try to `Open()` this connection and check for exceptions here. Not sure that's the most efficient, though...

Comment: Thanks. I originally had this implemented and was checking this way, but found that users still got an UE if the database went offline during a set of reads etc for an already open connection. ie: Open connection, create data reader etc, if during the read the server is unavailable, it is just represented as an unhandled exception to the user.